# Is it possible to listen/monitor messages send from a user to an another on Openfire Server using Smack API?

Tags: xmpp, openfire, smack

is it possible to listen / monitor messages send from a user to an another on Openfire Server using Smack API

Answer (score 0):

No, that would be a privacy violation, because it would mean that a third party is able to intercept and read messages between two JIDs.

Of course, you can modify any XMPP server to relay certain XMPP stanzas to a third party. But since there is no XEP that defines a API for such a mechanism, it's also not available in Smack.